# es-lint error can ot be disabled in react

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I had an eslint error when I try to commit the branch

```
147:14  error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

I can not find the problem in the code, also I tried to add

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
```

or

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
```

But still got the same error

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const setFile:any = []
    const addedFiles:any = acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles.map((item:File) => {
      if(item !== null){
        return {
          title: item?.name as string,
          fileName: item?.name as string,
          mediaType: 'SO',
          compositionType: 'O',
          album: ''
        };
      }else {[]}
    });
    setFile.push(addedFiles)
    if(addedFiles){ // **** the line 147
      setFileList([...addedFiles, ...fileList])
    }
    acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles.map((item:File) => {
      onUpload({
      title: item?.name as string,
      fileName: item?.name as string,
      mediaType: 'SO',
      compositionType: 'O',
      album: ''
    });
    })
  }, [acceptedFiles]);

  return (...
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to prefix the rule name with `@typescript-eslint/`.

To disable that rule inline use:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

Alternatively, in your .eslintrc file, disable the rule with the setting

```json
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off"
```

Comment: Actually I tried some different kinds of eslint-disable, also I tried again your suggestion, but nothing is working, it still giving the same error :(